# Let (Y,d) be a complete metric space, and let G be a family of continuous functions from Y to $\mathbb R$...

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space, and $F$ be a family of continuous functions from X to $\mathbb R$.  Suppose that for each $x\in X$ there exists $M_x\in$$\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)\le M_x$ for all $f \in F$.  Prove there exists an open ball $B=$ { $x\in X|d(x,x_o)<\epsilon$ } and a constant $M\in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x)\le M$ for $f\in F$ and all $x\in B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $A_n=\{x\in X:M_x\le n\}$; clearly $X=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}A_n$. $X$ is complete, so by the Baire category theorem there are an $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ and a non-empty open $U\subseteq X$ such that $U\subseteq\operatorname{cl}A_m$.

Comment: I have seen Baire's Thm. before but not worked with it much or Baire spaces.  I fail to see how your statement falls from that theorem.  I mean I realize since X is a complete metric space then X is a Baire space but I dont see how that gives your statement. Can you elaborate there?

Comment: @TyBrand: What version have you seen? The one that you need here is (BCT3) [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem).

Comment: Ah I see.  I had seen BCT1 and BCT2 before but not 3.  That makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: @TyBrand: You’re welcome!